# Joomla don't like my custom htaccess to redirect a page

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

I have a joomla website with several permanent redirection ( [R=301,L] ) and the standard joomla redirection:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

I have a page on my website that I call like that:

`https://mywebsite/e-shop` 
or 
`https://mywebsite/e-shop?filter=somewords`

And I would like it to become:

`https://mywebsite/e-shop` 
or
`https://mywebsite/e-shop-somewords`

The only way it works is this one:

```
RewriteRule ^e-shop-somewords$ /e-shop?filter=somewords  [R=301,L]
```

But this is not what I wan't.
So I did these tries:

```
RewriteRule ^e-shop-([a-z]+)$ /e-shop?filter=$1  [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^e-shop-somewords$ /e-shop?filter=somewords  [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^e-shop-somewords$ /e-shop?filter=somewords  [QSA]
```

But I always get the joomla 404 page.

EDIT: I understand what happens, I'm calling https://mywebsite/e-shop-somewords then my rule is applied so the new page is https://mywebsite/e-shop?filter=somewords which exists for joomla but not physically so the joomla rule is applied and the new page is https://mywebsite/index.php 
The problem is that the uri that I suppose joomla uses is /e-shop-somewords and that page doesn't exists for joomla, so I get the 404.